# Signing Apache Cordova Android app

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to release an Android application using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova 5.1.1
I create a keystore file and edit the build.json with the data for the keystore as shown [here](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#android)

I get errors

```
Command failed with exit code 1 ERROR building one of the platforms

Command failed with exit code 1 MDAVSCLI
```

When I rebuild the project I get

```
MSB3073 The command "platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat" exited with code 1
```

...\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like clean.bat is failing to reset the state of the project. Can you try deleting the platforms\android directory and retry?

Comment: When I delete platforms\android directory the rebuild succeeds, but when I try to run the release it gives the first two errors again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try updating your Cordova tools to version 3? We made a fix that might address this issue. It's hard to tell without seeing the entire log (disclosure: I work for Microsoft).